# Error in R with the MAPE function, how can I solve?

Tags: r, model, predict

I build a model

```
model.5 <- lm(formula = rent ~ area + rooms + age + nationality + maritalstat + education + traveltime + region + center, data=mysample)
```

and now I did the prediction

```
sel <- is.na(mysample$rent)

predict(model.5, newdata=subset(mysample, sel), interval="pred")

newprediction <- predict(model.5, newdata=subset(mysample, sel), interval="prediction")
```

**I would like to know why my MAPE doesn't work**

```
MAPE(newprediction, mysample$rent)
```

Can someone please help me? I would be very pleased.

All the best

Comment: Check `class(newprediction)`, if you are asking `predict` for an interval, it's not a vector.

Comment: > MAPE (newprediction, mysample$rent)
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In ref - x :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In (ref - x)/ref :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is a space after the MAPE function (right before the opening parenthesis). That could cause an error.

If that doesnt solve your issue, it would help a lot if you could share the error message you get.

Comment: *That could cause an error*: no, it couldn't. The R parser can handle that.

Comment: > MAPE (newprediction, mysample$rent)
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In ref - x :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In (ref - x)/ref :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: @Uhtredbr You are fitting with the full data set `mysample` but predicting with a subset. Since `newprediction` and `mysample$rent` have different lengths you get a warning. Try fitting with the subset and run everything again.